# How to differentiate the same method invocations

Tags: c#

I'll start with a code example. I have a following class

```
public class Foo
{
    public object DoSomething() {}
}
```

I also have some code that utilises method `DoSomehting` from class `Foo`.

```
public class Boo
{
    privite Foo foo;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ...
        foo.DoSomething();
        ...
        foo.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

**How could I distinguish those two calls `foo.DoSomething()` inside the `Foo` class?**

What I came up with is to have an identification object passed in parameters for each call to `DoSomething`. Then in `Foo` class I would store the ids and compare them when new call is made.

```
public class Boo
{
    privite Foo foo;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ...
        var idObjA = new IDObj(Guid.NewGuid());
        foo.DoSomething(idObjA);
        ...
        var idObjB = new IDObj(Guid.NewGuid());
        foo.DoSomething(idObjB);
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to do it, or a pattern that I'm not aware of. I want the utilising code to be the least obscured so calls to the `DoSomething` method are as simple as possible.

To clarify my intentions. I'm implementing a message service with an ability for the user to check a checkbox on dialog box (e.g. Do not show again, or Apply to all). Code utilising the service can call the same method multiple times, to show an error message for example, but in different context. In other words, when user decided to not show that message again for particular action message box should not appear. Thus I need to know when method was called multiple times in the same context (action)

Comment: A method should not be dependent on the caller. It shouldn't even care about the caller.

Comment: You can overload Dosomething() to take in different data types. Depending on the data type of the parameter passed, it will know what to do.

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish the calls? What should DoSomething do differently in each case? It sounds like a case where you need either a) different overloads of DoSomething, or b) two entirely different methods in the Foo class. Since we don't know the real use case, it's hard to give specific advice about how to structure it. You haven't quite given us enough information about what you're doing.

Comment: Just put it this way, you call your friend twice without telling them anything they will get confused too.

Comment: @ADyson To clarify my intentions. I'm implementing a message service with an ability for the user to check a checkbox on dialog box (e.g. *Do not show again*, or *Apply to all*). Code utilising the service can call the same method multiple times, to show an error message for example, but in different context. 
In other words, when user decided to not show that message again for particular action message box should not appear. Thus I need to know when method was called multiple times in the same context (action).

Comment: I added your info to the question - that's where it belongs, not in the comments. But thanks for replying.

Comment: So pass in a context object that tracks the response for that context.

Comment: The problem with using `Guid.NewGuid()` is that the return is session-dependent, so the user's choices can't be persisted between sessions.  I'd suggest using a bunch of `const string contextNameX = "Context 1";` declarations to track the contexts.  You could bundle them all up in some static class if you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the extra info in your edit, it sounds like what you perhaps need to be doing is setting a separate property in your `Foo` class showing whether the "apply to all" or "do not show again" option has been checked for a particular context.

Then when you call `DoSomething`, it can check that property to know if it should show the dialog or not.

So in the simplest case you might do something like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool DoNotShow { get; set; };

    public void DoSomething() {
        if(this.DoNotShow == true) {
            // logic
        } else {
            // alternative logic
        }
    }
}

public class Boo
{
    privite Foo foo;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ...
        foo.DoSomething();
        foo.DoNotShow = true;
        ...
        foo.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

The value could then be toggled on and off whenever you like.

N.B. You mentioned different "contexts" in which dialogs can be turned on and off.

For this, you could consider either giving this property the ability to store values for different contexts (e.g. in something like a Dictionary, perhaps) and then passing in the current context name to the DoSomething method when it's called. Or even pass in a totally separate "context" object to DoSomething each time, which contains the context name *and* the boolean indicating whether to show the dialog or not.

Or...using a different instance of `Foo` for each context might actually be more in line with object-oriented principles (in which case you could probably use the code exactly as per my example above). Again it depends exactly how the class the and the overall application works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should expand a bit on what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you're using your instantiated class like described above and are just trying to differentiate between the first and second call, you can add a respective toggle field in your `Foo` class:

```
public class Foo
{
    private bool _firstCall = true;

    public object DoSomething() {
        if(_firstCall) {
            _firstCall = false;
            // first call logic
        } else {
            // second call logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There could be more invocation to the method so it cannot be fixed with if statements

Answer (score 0):

If knowing the line number of the call helps, you could use one of the methods for getting the caller information described [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/07/25/c.net-little-wonders-getting-caller-information.aspx). So for example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public object DoSomething() {
        StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1, true);
        var method = frame.GetMethod();
        var lineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
    }
}
```

Comment: Be advised this requires debugging symbols.